# Why is Proguard not obfuscating my code?

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

When I build a release build of the app Proguard runs, but on looking at the APK using APK Analyzer everything is readable with apparently no obfuscation being applied.

My intent is to apply obfuscation to the APK to make reverse engineering a little more difficult.

```
Gradle:

buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Proguard is definitely running as I can see that in the Gradle console.

```
proguard-rules.pro:

-dontshrink
-dontoptimize

-keep class com.squareup.picasso.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.squareup.picasso.**

-keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**

-keep class kotlin.reflect.** { *; }
-dontwarn kotlin.reflect.**

-keep class javax.annotation.** { *; }
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**

-keep class org.codehaus.mojo.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.**
```

The Proguard docs say obfuscation runs by default. The docs also say classes specified in keep statements will not be obfuscated, but the classes in the app itself are not specified in keep statements, but are still not obfuscated.

On looking further, there is a file in the build folder called aapt_rules.txt that contains what look like keep statements for every class in the app. I don't understand why that would be.

How do I reconfigure Proguard so it obfuscates all of the code in my app (not the libraries), without shrinking or removing any classes?

Answer (score 0):

by looking at line `keep class com.squareup.picasso.** { *; }`and `-keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }` ,

you are not obfuscating anything which are part of above packages or sub packages.

Progaurd will obfuscate anything which is not part of above package and sub package.

do you have class outside of these packages.

Comment: All the classes in the keep statements in proguard-rules.pro are library classes the project uses. What needs obfuscating is the project code itself, which is not mentioned in that file.

Comment: can you share proguard_seed.txt file and proguard_map.txt